# Datalist - No databind to server control, extract possible?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, ado.net, datalist

In a datalist, you usually extract row data with a FindControl on a control that is assigned a value via a databind using say, Eval.

What if in your datalist, there is no bind to an ASP.NET server control?  It's in a datalist, "straight up", in say a table cell or on its own.

You can't do a FindControl, so is it possible to extract a row value if it's not bound and not a datakey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value is within a DataList, you can still `FindControl` it, provided that it's inside a control marked with `runat="server"`:

```
<asp:Literal id="ltFixedValue" runat="server">5</asp:Literal>
```

or even

```
<span id="spFixedValue" runat="server">5</span>
```

Comment: I wanted to stay away from literal, but I think I have no choice.  Maybe span will might be a little better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there is data bound to your datalist (cause it's rendering an item template).  I would use something like this in the datalist's OnItemDatabound event:

if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
myobject obj = (myobject)e.Item.DataItem;
}

Once you have cast the dataitem than u can extract the value you need.

Comment: I'm actually setting the data in this event and want to get data via a button click.  I guess I could save the data in this event in viewstate, but I'd have 2 copies of the same data.  I don't think I can avoid using runat server.

Comment: I think you may want to wire the data you need captured into the command argument of the target button - then the value is available in the OnClick method you created.